# raw resource from an Activity to an other Activity to be played with SoundPool

Tags: java, android, soundpool

This is my project:

Activity 1

```
    int ThePlayedSound= R.raw.Sound_ID;

    Intent MyIntent= new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
           MyIntent.putExtra("key",ThePlayedSound);
    startActivity(MyIntent);
```

Activity 2

I want to play the raw source with a Sound Pool With a clicking button so:

```
    Intent MyIntent=getIntent();
    int ThePlayedSound= MyIntent.getIntExtra("key", 0);

    Sound_Pool_thing= new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
    Click = Sound_Pool_thing.load(this,ThePlayedSound , 1);

    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound_Pool_thing.play(Click,1,1,1,0,1);

        }
    });
```

**Edited : 
and when i try to open the app I got Unfortunately , My_App has stopped**

I can't figure it out ..Help =)

**Editing adding the complete code for the second Activity**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    SoundPool Sound_Pool_thing;
    int Click;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2_main);

        Intent MyIntent=getIntent();
        int ThePlayedSound= MyIntent.getIntExtra("key", 0);

        Sound_Pool_thing= new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);

        Click = Sound_Pool_thing.load(this,ThePlayedSound , 1);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sound_Pool_thing.play(Click,1,1,1,0,1);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: what exception does it gives ?

Comment: Click: 0  Sound_Pool_thing: SoundPool @4298 ThePlayedSound : 0

Comment: I got this on debugging this line         Click = Sound_Pool_thing.load(this,ThePlayedSound , 1);

Comment: can you post your crash log here  and the full activity code for Activity 2?

Comment: @mdb_5203 done I added the full code but I couldn't get the log...Although the line that causing this is  `        Click = Sound_Pool_thing.load(this,ThePlayedSound , 1);
`
and from debugging I got this
Click: 0    Sound_Pool_thing: SoundPool @4298   ThePlayedSound : 0

Answer (score 0):

@Claudenix, I guess the problem is with your file name used for sound file i.e Sound_ID.

int ThePlayedSound= R.raw.Sound_ID;

try renaming the file in your raw folder in lowercase for eg:- "sound_id"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope I don't think so, I'm already using a simple name "water"...thank you anyway =)

Comment: thats strange ?